# Osano Cookie Consent - move button to the left

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Osano Cookie Consent informational notice about cookies.
This example:

```
https://www.osano.com/cookieconsent/examples/example-3-informational.html
```

I would like to move "Got it!" button from right side to the left.

Is it possible to do that using its initialise script?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `float: right` in class of text and `float: left` in class of button.